# Why does ArrayAdapter accept ArrayList<String> but not Set<String> as paramenter?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I've implemented a ListView with OnItemClickListener, the ArrayAdapter accepts an `ArrayList<String>` as parameter but not a `Set<String>`.

This works:

```
ArrayList<String> myEntries = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter;

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.listviewitem, myEntries);
listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

This doesn't work:

```
Hashtable<String, File> myEntries = new Hashtable<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter;

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.listviewitem, myEntries.keySet());
listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(com.example.MainActivity, int, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)'
```

Both myEntries store Strings, why doesn't ArrayAdapter accept the `Set<String>`?

Comment: Look at the overloads available. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: You can'T Beacuse ArrayAdapter's Constructor doesn't take accept type Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why doesn't ArrayAdapter accept the Set?

Because the API doesn't have a constructor overload that is compatible with `Set`.

My guess is that that is because a `Set` cannot be indexed; i.e. it is not "array like".  The `ArrayAdapter` is designed to adapt arrays and things that behave like arrays.

Here are a couple of alternatives:

- You could copy the set contents to a list or array, and continue to use ArrayAdapter.  Problem: changes made through the adapter won't update the original set.
- You could switch to a CursorAdapter, and implement (or find) a Cursor class that provides a read-only or read-write cursor over your set.  Problem: that will only work for a set implementation that provides a stable ordering for its elements.  `HashSet` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the [javadoc for ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E)), it can take a List.  ArrayList is a type of List.  A Set is not a type of List, so the compiler rejects it.

A List is required by ArrayAdapter because a Set doesn't have a natural ordering, so it doesn't make sense to show a Set in an ordered list if you don't know what the order is.  You can still convert the Set to a type of List if you don't care about the ordering, and you can sort the resulting List as needed.